How to factor expressions with a negative rational power
This is the expression: $6x^{\frac{1}{2}}-5x^{-\frac{1}{4}}+1$.
I had a similar problem. It was like this: $x+2x^{\frac{1}{2}}-8$. I solved it by turning $x$ into $x^{\frac{2}{2}}$  and marking $t=x^{\frac{1}{4}}$. I substituted $t$ into the expression and solved the quadratic equation. But in next problem, I have a negative exponent. Can you please show me how to write the expression in quadratic form?
Edit: I looked at the answer and it was: $(2x^{-1/4}-1)(3x^{-1/4}-1)$. I tried to solve it and I got a similar answer but mine was $x^{1/4}$ instead of $x^{-1/4}$.

So here, the $x^{1/2}$ and $x^{-1/4}$ don't have the property that one is the square of the other, so no substitution will make it a quadratic expression. So what you want to do depends on what the final goal is. If the final goal is to find roots, you can multiply everything by $x^{1/4}$ and make a substitution to get a cubic equation (from which you would need to eliminate $x=0$ as a solution in the end if it were one).

If you had three powers such that two of them add up to the third one, then you might be able to do something, but that isn't true here either.

Is it possible that the $1/2$ is a typo and it was supposed to be $-1/2$?

Yes, it is possible. Because this problem is from an Uzbek edition of a soviet math textbook. I encountered some typos in both exercises and explanation texts before. I think they made these types while translating to Uzbek language.

so, what do you think, should i delete the question as it may be wrong?

The solution book implies that it the first exponent should be $-1/2$ instead of $+1/2$. In this case it's fine, you just need to use $x^{-1/4}$ as your substitution variable.
